# PHP Select from two tables and echo table name

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I am using this PHP code to select from 2 tables in MySQL using UNION

```
$sql="
    SELECT 
    'ticket_updates' as rowTable,
    sequence, 
    ticket_seq, 
    notes as displaydata, 
    datetime as timestamp, 
    updatedby, 
    CONCAT('<strong>Time Start: </strong>',timestart,' - <strong>Time End: </strong>',timeend) as timestartend
    from ticket_updates where ticket_seq = '".$_GET["seq"]."'

    UNION

    SELECT 
    'ticket_changes' as rowTable,
    sequence, 
    ticket_seq, 
    description as displaydata, 
    datetime as timestamp,  
    changed_by as updatedby, 
    blankfield
    from ticket_changes where ticket_seq = '".$_GET["seq"]."' 

    ORDER by timestamp ASC ";

$stmt = $pdo_conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array(':ticket_seq' => $_GET["seq"]));
$records = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$num_rows = count($records);
foreach ($records as $result2) {
   echo $result2["rowTable"];
}
```

but its not echoing either `ticket_updates` or `ticket_changes`

i know there is rows being returned because when i run the query in phpMyAdmin its showing rows and it shows either `ticket_updates` or `ticket_changes`

Comment: please format your code properly

Comment: Where is `:ticket_seq` in your SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't have any placeholders in your SQL to match the parameter in your `execute` call. Try this:

```
$sql="
    SELECT 
    'ticket_updates' as rowTable,
    sequence, 
    ticket_seq, 
    notes as displaydata, 
    datetime as timestamp, 
    updatedby, 
    CONCAT('<strong>Time Start: </strong>',timestart,' - <strong>Time End: </strong>',timeend) as timestartend
    from ticket_updates where ticket_seq = :ticket_seq1

    UNION

    SELECT 
    'ticket_changes' as rowTable,
    sequence, 
    ticket_seq, 
    description as displaydata, 
    datetime as timestamp,  
    changed_by as updatedby, 
    blankfield
    from ticket_changes where ticket_seq = :ticket_seq2 

    ORDER by timestamp ASC ";

$stmt = $pdo_conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array(':ticket_seq1' => $_GET["seq"], ':ticket_seq12' => $_GET["seq"]));
```

You need two different placeholders, you can't use the same one twice.

Comment: i have tried this  but its still not showing the table name when i echo $result2["rowTable"]

Comment: Then I can't explain why `$result2["rowTable"]` isn't working. Look at `var_dump($records)`, do you see the column in there?

Comment: yep i can see it in var_dump($records); "/

Comment: If it's in `$records`, then there's no reason why the `foreach` loop shouldn't print it. Are you sure your code exactly matches what you wrote in the question? There's probably a typo somewhere. Make sure you have error reporting turned up full.